# How to take a partial derivative of $\|y - Xw\|^2$ with respect to w?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, vectors, partial-derivative, normed-spaces

So I've tried to solve this problem where we are asked to solve the partial derivative of function $\sum(y - Xw)^2$ or $\|y-Xw\|^2$ and  then minimize it. I've never done any linear algebra aside some really basic stuff and I can't seem to find any information how to take partial derivative of such a function. I know how to take partial derivative of simple function but not functions with $\||x||^2$ notation.

In this case it would probably help to denote some variable e.g $\ z=y-Xw $ that way we get $\|z\|^2 $. Is this even a right approach? I have no clue what to do after this.

Comment: Write it out explicitly in two dimensions with $y=(y_1,y_2)$ and $w=(w_1,w_2)$ and just take partial derivatives.

Comment: I don't know if I understand completely what you mean. Could you give some kind of steps how to do this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: If $X$ is the identity matrix you'll get $(y_1-w_1)^2 + (y_2-w_2)^2$. If the matrix $X$ is in there, you'll get $\big(y_1-(x_{11}w_1 + x_{12}w_2)\big)^2 + \big(y_2-(x_{21}w_1 + x_{22}w_2)\big)^2$. :)

Answer (score 4):

An easy way to do it is write it like scalar product and then use the properties of the scalar product. I assume you are working with real matrix and vectors (it really seems that you are dealing with Ordinary Least Squares). 
\begin{align}
\|y-Xw\|^2 &=\langle y-Xw,y-Xw \rangle \\
&=y^Ty-2w^TX^Ty+w^TX^TXw.
\end{align}
I've just used the fact that the scalar product is bilinear and symmetric. Now just take the derivative and use the product rule:
$$\implies -2X^Ty+2X^TXw=0 \\ \implies X^Ty=X^TXw \\ \implies w=(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty.$$ If you have problem with the derivation in general just write it down the two dimensional case.

Comment: When you use the `<` and `>` signs, are you detailing the inner product of the elements contained?

Comment: yes, i like that notation.